# confix.xml in crosswalk-cordova app ignored

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I followed [this official guide](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/develop_an_application.html) to build a cordova crosswalk app.

I chose the approach of creating a new cordova app with the cordova binaries from the cordova-crosswalk zip file (instead of migrating an existing app).

Everything works fine except that the values I've been putting in config.xml  (top level or in the `/res/xml` directory) are simply ignored.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: may be it would help if you show the parameters that you are trying to use (provide the content of config.xml and detail what is ignored)

Comment: Basic params like `widget.version` or `name` :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess, you are upgrading the config.xml in the platforms/android folder instead of the one at the root of the project?

A cordova crosswalk project is just a crosswalk project where you replace the cordovalib in the android platform, but once that done, you can continue to configure it using the cli from the root of the project and the config.xml in the root too.

The config.xml in the root of the project and the one in platforms are quite different and I don't think they support the same parameters.

Comment: Projects created with the cordova binary included in the crosswalk-cordova bundle do not contain a `platforms/android` directory. The whole directory structure is a bit different than if you create a vanilla cordova project and then just replace the webview with crosswalk.